# How to alter URL loading in a webview?

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

The basic idea is to alter every url being loaded in a webview (for example adding/removing get parameters).

I have a custom `WebViewClient`, in which I have the following method :

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    String modifiedUrl = Util.someMethod(url);
    super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, modifiedUrl);
}
```

Will it work or should I put this logic in another method, for example `onPagestarted` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rather should do something like :

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(conditionForModifyingUrl){
        String modifiedUrl = Util.someMethod(url);
        view.loadUrl(modifiedUrl);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Calling `super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, modifiedUrl)` won't work because, as it is its name, this method only checks if the url should be overridden, and does not load the url at all.

Comment: I also thought of this approach, but isn't it risky to completely stop and relaunch an URL loading (data loss, etc...) ?

Comment: There's no problem, but consider that loadUrl will call shouldOverrideUrlLoading. So be sure to have a correct condition, in order to not have a infinite loop (it should return false at the end)